# Relationship issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, erd

I'm working on a ERD with mysql workbench, and i have a little question.

I have a Database with this tables:

1. company_address
2. country
3. state
4. city

I want to store the address of the company with all the data (country, state, and cuty). The relation between thos tables are:

```
 - country
   - id
   - name

- state
  - country_id
  - name

- city
  - state_id
  - name
```

My question is, what is better, put te relation of the company_addres just with the city?.

```
- company_address
  - city_id
  - company_name
  - more_fieds
```

Or put all FK of the location tables?

```
- company_address
  - city_id
  - state_id
  - country_id
  - company_name
  - more_fields
```

Wich one is the better way?. Or wich one will slow down the performance.
Thanks!

Comment: What if there were a city that is in two states?  Is "Kansas City" one city or two cities?

Answer (score 0):

According to database normalization technique create a separate for city, state and country. However if you're having only few records in company address table and there is no other tables are need address info, I think there is no point creating multiple tables.